# I want to hide header of my main stack navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

const auth is my main navigator in which I call all other 3 stack navigators. problem is that this main stack navigator has its own header and i am using my own customized header in other pages of the application. now the problem is my application shows two headers 1 from main stack navigator and 2nd my customized navigator I can't find any good solution to fix this problem kindly suggests what I do thanks

```js
const authSwitch = createStackNavigator ({
  navigationOptions:{
    headerShown:false
  },
    SignInStack : createStackNavigator({
      Login :  { screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions:{
        header:null,
      }},
      Home :  { screen: HomeScreen, navigationOptions: { header: null }},
    }),
    
    SignUpStack :  createStackNavigator({
      MobileCheck :  { screen: MobileCheck,navigationOptions:{header:null}},
      VerifyCode :  { screen: VerifyCode},
      Login :  { screen: LoginScreen},
      Home :  { screen: HomeScreen},

  }),
    ForgotPasswordStack : createStackNavigator({
        MobileCheckFP : {screen:MobileCheckFP,navigationOptions:{header:null}},   //enter mobile no 
        ForgotPassword : ForgotPassword,  //enter OTP , new pass and confirm pass
        Login : LoginScreen,
        Home : HomeScreen,
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the headerMode:'none' on navigator level

```
const authSwitch = createStackNavigator (
  {
   SignInStack : createStackNavigator({
      Login :  { screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions:{
        headerShown: false,
      }},
      Home :  { screen: HomeScreen, navigationOptions: { headerShown: false }},
    }),
    
    SignUpStack :  createStackNavigator({
      MobileCheck :  { screen: MobileCheck,navigationOptions:{ headerShown: false }},
      VerifyCode :  { screen: VerifyCode},
      Login :  { screen: LoginScreen},
      Home :  { screen: HomeScreen},

  }),
    ForgotPasswordStack : createStackNavigator({
        MobileCheckFP : {screen:MobileCheckFP,navigationOptions:{ headerShown: false }},   //enter mobile no 
        ForgotPassword : ForgotPassword,  //enter OTP , new pass and confirm pass
        Login : LoginScreen,
        Home : HomeScreen,
    })
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);
```

I couldnt test by adding your screens, but this should work.